# Mixed-Mode Process vs. Managed-to-Unmanaged IPC

Tags: c++, .net, garbage-collection, c++-cli, ipc

I am trying to come up with design candidates for a current project that I am working on. Its client interface is based on WCF Services exposing public methods and call backs. Requests are routed all the way to C++ libraries (that use boost) that perform calculations, operations, etc.

The current scheme is based on a WCF Service talking to a separate native C++ process via IPC.

To make things a little simpler, there is a recommendation around here to go mixed-mode (i.e. to have a single .NET process which loads the native C++ layer inside it, most likely communicating to it via a very thin C++/CLI layer). The main concern is whether garbage collection or other .NET aspects would hinder the performance of the unmanaged C++ part of the process.

I started looking up concepts of safe points and and GC helper methods (e.g. KeepAlive(), etc.) but I couldn't find any direct discussion about this or benchmarks. From what I understand so far, one of the safe points is if a thread is executing unamanged code and in this case garbage collection does *not* suspend any threads (is this correct?) to perform the cleanup.

I guess the main question I have is there a performance concern on the native side when running these two types of code in the same process vs. having separate processes.

Comment: A single process will almost always be faster. The only question is how *much* faster (at least from what I've seen).

Comment: Thanks, Jeffry. So in your opinion, taking the managed-to-unmanaged transitions/thunking out of the equation, you believe the *native code* execution performance would be practically the same whether it's in a purely native process or a mixed-mode process, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a thread that has never executed any managed code, it will not be frozen during .NET garbage collection.

If a thread which uses managed code is currently running in native code, the garbage collector won't freeze it, but instead mark the thread to stop when it next reaches managed code.  However, if you're thinking of a native dispatch loop that doesn't return for a long time, you may find that you're blocking the garbage collector (or leaving stuff pinned causing slow GC and fragmentation).  So I recommend keeping your threads performing significant tasks in native code completely pure.

Making sure that the compiler isn't silently generating MSIL for some standard C++ code (thereby making it execute as managed code) is a bit tricky.  But in the end you can accomplish this with careful use of `#pragma managed(push, off)`.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to get a mixed mode application up and running, however it can be very hard to get it working well.

I would advise thinking carefully before choosing that design - in particular about how you layer your application and the sort of lifetimes you expect for your unmanaged objects. A few thoughts from past experiences:

1. C++ object lifetime - by architecture.
   Use C++ objects briefly in local scope then dispose of them immediately.
   It sounds obvious but worth stating, C++ objects are unmanaged resources that are designed to be used as unmanaged resources.  Typically they expect deterministic creation and destruction - often making extensive use of RAII.  This can be very awkward to control from a a managed program. The IDispose pattern exists to try and solve this.  This can work well for short lived objects but is rather tedious and difficult to get right for long lived objects.  In particular if you start making unmanaged objects members of managed classes rather than things that live in function scope only, very quickly every class in your program has to be IDisposable and suddenly managed programming becomes harder than ummanaged programming.
2. The GC is too aggressive.
   Always worth remembering that when we talk about managed objects going out of scope we mean in the eyes of the IL compiler/runtime not the language that you are reading the code in. If an ummanaged object is kept around as a member and a managed object is designed to delete it things can get complicated.  If your dispose pattern is not complete from top to bottom of your program the GC can get rather aggressive.  Say for example you try to write a managed class which deletes an unmanaged object in its finaliser.  Say the last thing you do with the managed object is access the unmanaged pointer to call a method.  Then the GC may decide that during that unmanaged call is a great time to collect the managed object.  Suddenly your unmanaged pointer is deleted mid method call.
3. The GC is not aggressive enough.
   If you are working within address constraints (e.g. you need a 32 bit version) then you need to remember that the GC holds on to memory unless it thinks it needs to let go.  Its only input to these thoughts is the managed world. If the unmanaged allocator needs space there is no connection to the GC.  An unmanaged allocation can fail simply because the GC hasn't collected objects that are long out of scope.  There is a memory pressure API but again it is only really usable/useful for quite simple designs.
4. Buffer copying.  You also need to think about where to allocate any large memory blocks.  Managed blocks can be pinned to look like unmanaged blocks.  Unmanaged blocks can only ever be copied if they need to look like managed blocks.  However when will that large managed block actually get released?